# using fortran derived type variable without %

Tags: fortran, derived-types

I define a type named `MATRIX` and a variable of this type named `A` as the following

```
TYPE MATRIX
    REAL, ALLOCATABLE, DIMENSION(:,:) :: MAT
END TYPE

TYPE(MATRIX) :: A
```

the usual way of constructing `A` and then using it is

```
ALLOCATE(A%MAT(2,2))

A%MAT(1,:) = [1,2]
A%MAT(2,:) = [3,4]

PRINT*, A%MAT
```

I'd like to know that if it's possible to work with variable `A` without having to write `A%MAT`. In other words, is there any workaround to rewrite the former block of code in the following form (using `A` instead of `A%MAT`)

```
ALLOCATE(A(2,2))

A(1,:) = [1,2]
A(2,:) = [3,4]

PRINT*, A
```

Comment: One option is to use a [parameterized derived type](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/fortran-compiler-oneapi-dev-guide-and-reference/top/language-reference/data-types-constants-and-variables/derived-data-types/parameterized-derived-type-declarations.html), so you would not need an allocatable array member. Another options would be to pass an already allocated arrays as argument to the constructor. Or even a custom constructor.

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues I do not think that solves the need for the `%` syntax. Masoud is probably looking for some defined operations (custom additions, assignments, IO, inexing). Sadly, overloading the indexing is not possible in Fortran.

Comment: You can set the whole array in one go with a constructor, or by overloading the assignment operator appropriately. But you can't specify individual elements or slices without a %, at least as far as I can see

Comment: Yeah... the `print*, a` can be achieved with a [custom derived-type I/O](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/xffbg/121.141?topic=statements-user-defined-derived-type-inputoutput-fortran-2003). The object initialization, you could get something like `a = matrix(2, 2)` with a custom constructor, or `allocate(matrix(2, 2) :: a)` with parameterized type. But for the `a(1, :) = [1, 2]` there is no way, it can only be interpreted as if `a` is an array (or character). No indexing overloading in fortran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the syntax `a(1,:) = [1,2]` where `a` is a derived type is not currently allowed by the Fortran standard (Fortran 2018 at the time of writing).

There is [a proposal](https://github.com/j3-fortran/fortran_proposals/issues/119) to allow this in a future Fortran standard.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `associate` statement to bind certain expressions to a shorter name. This can be used to give a name to a component of a variable.

```
    allocate(A%mat(2, 2))
    associate(B => A%mat(:, :))
        B(1,:) = [1, 2]
        B(2,:) = [3, 4]
        write(*, *) B
    end associate
```

Note that you can also use `reshape` and automatic allocation to get rid of some slices.

```
! No allocate statement necessary.
A%mat = reshape([1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 2])
```

Comment: Good point, but `B` could only be used in the `associate` block not all over the program body. Furthermore, I'd rather a workaround that doesn't need introducing another auxiliary variables for `A`.

Comment: > Furthermore, I'd rather a workaround that doesn't need introducing another auxiliary variables for A.

You can just do `associate(A => A%mat)` (overshadowing the original `A` of derived type)