# A more efficient way to directly use member variables of a derived type without using the percentage sign

Tags: fortran, derived-types, associate

As shown in [using fortran derived type variable without %](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68205061/using-fortran-derived-type-variable-without),  we can use associate to avoid using the percentage sign. An example is as below:

```
    program test
    type z_type
    real x,y
    end type z_type
    type(z_type) :: z
    associate (x=>z%x)
    associate (y=>z%y)
    x=10
    y=10
    write(6,*)z%x,z%y
    end associate
    end associate
    end
```

But if I have too many member variables in the derived type, are there any "efficient " way for me to get what the above "associate " approach does?
Thanks.
An update: the problem is that I am refactoring a legacy code, in which I need to wrap up many variables to a derived type structure. But I hope I don't need to add to each variable in the block of the previous codes with the derived data name followed by % sign.

Comment: What do you mean by efficient? Short/terse?

Comment: I meant "short"  for coding and reading. Thanks.

Comment: To clarify: you know you can do `associate(x=>z%x, y=>z%y)` rather than have two associate constructs?

Comment: I hope it's not terse - the above is verging on unreadable for me. A bit of indentation would be a start.

Comment: We do need a much better idea of your real problem, though, to give any "good" advice. For example, for your program I'd say just `print*, z_type(10.,10.)` and not bother with any `%`s...

Comment: @fancescalus,  thanks. Yes, I know I can do multiple variables association in one associate command.    I will try to add some clarification in my question.

Comment: What you would like is an equivalent of the `with` statement of Pascal/Delphi, but it doesn't exist in Fortran.

Comment: *But if I have too many member variables in the derived type ...* well then, you have too many member variables don't you!  Seriously, this might point towards a problem which is better solved by redefining your data structures than by seeking ways to abbreviate your code.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark  Thanks for your point.  Yes, I agree a more suitable data structure should be considered, though the current one is still kept because of my current stratragy in  refactoring of the legacy codes.  Maybe, I should figure out another strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could use pointers, I suppose, but it's a bit unnatural.

```
program test
   implicit none

   type z_type
      real x, y
   end type z_type

   type(z_type), target :: z
   real, pointer :: x, y

   x => z%x
   y => z%y

   x = 10
   y = 20

   write( *, * ) z

end program test
```

If the variables were all of one type then Fortran arrays are devastatingly effective:

```
program test
   implicit none

   type z_type
      real x(2)
   end type z_type

   type(z_type) z
   z%x = [ 10, 20 ]

   write( *, * ) z

end program test
```

Overall, it might be better to make z_type a proper class, with its own type-bound procedures (aka member functions) and just make it object-oriented programming.

```
module modz
   implicit none

   type z_type
      real x, y
   contains
      procedure write_me
   end type z_type

contains

   subroutine write_me( this )
      class(z_type), intent(in) :: this
      write( *, *) this%x, this%y
   end subroutine write_me

end module modz

!=======================================

program test
   use modz
   implicit none

   type(z_type) :: z = z_type( 10, 20 )
   call z%write_me

end program test
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your rather complete descriptions of your answers.   Your suggestion to use the derived data-bound method seems the best approach I can try ( how to pass those values to the derived data is another problem).  So, I will select this as the answer!